# Why can't I reliably read a value of memory from Chrome in my C++ app?

Tags: c++, memory

I'm very new to programming and C++. I'm using the latest edition of C++ primer to learn. I am developing on Windows with Visual Studio. I've successfully written an app that utilizes OpenCV and Tesseract to play a single player web-based game on Chrome. My next goal is to read memory values from Chrome instead of relying on Tesseract. Specifically, these are X and Y coordinates.

I am able to find the find the coordinate values I want by attaching Cheat Engine to Chrome. Then, I confirm the memory values via C++ code to read the process memory via the address. I want to understand how this memory is being handled, so that I can reliably find this value without requiring input of the memory addresses. I.E. I want to avoid having to run Cheat Engine to find my memory values and then input them into my C++ app via a config file or std::cin.

The coordinates seem to follow some sort of pattern. For example, the X coordinate addresses all seem to end in **80209B74**. On first check it's 24D**80209B74**, when I relaunch the game in Chrome it has changed to 58**80209B74**. This pattern is consistent throughout several instances of Chrome. This is also consistent across other systems I check it on.

I believe I need to find some sort of base address; however, I think security features of Windows or Chrome are preventing me from doing this. Or, my lacking of understanding memory and its operation is the issue. When I run the GetModuleInformation command from the Windows API, I get a base address of 7FF72ACB0000.  That value is a lot bigger than my X coordinate address from Cheat Engine. Is there some sort of relative mapping here.I was hoping the command would return 5800000000. Then, I could just add my 80209B74 to that.

I also noticed that the base address, 7FF72ACB0000, is the same across the systems for the Chrome PID running my game.  From what I understand, this 7FFxx.. address is the virtual memory address for the process.

I would appreciate some guidance on tackling the problem or recommended reading material.

Main problem: How do I reliably get the part of the address that changes?

**24D**80209B74
**58**80209B74

I tried:

1. Enumerating the address with GetModuleInformation.
2. Disabling Windows ASLR and comparing memory values.
3. Searching for pointers in Cheat Engine.

Comment: `I think security features of Windows or Chrome are preventing me from doing this` yes, the OS will always load the app in a different random address in memory to stop you from doing exactly that.

Comment: Look up "ASLR" - Address Space Layout Randomisation.

Comment: @AhmedAEK I disabled ASLR on Windows and I get the same results. Does that completely stop it, or are apps able to override that? Also, I get the same exact base address, 7FF72ACB0000, on every system when running GetModuleInformation. Is that correct?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I turned off ASLR in Windows, and I still get the same above results. In Cheat engine I see that chrome.exe+1835D0 consistently maps to where my value is. That is consistent every time. Is there a way for me to find my value based on that?

Comment: Are you trying to learn how to make cheat engines for arbitrary programs, or are you trying to automate a web game?  The former is a very complicated and brittle way of accomplishing the latter.

Comment: @BenVoigt I am trying automate a web game. I am only using cheat engine for finding the values in memory so that I can learn. My goal is to not rely on cheat engine to find the memory address. Instead, I'd like my app to find the location of the x and y coordinates. The address seems to be some-what deterministic since the majority of it remains the same. (the last 8 characters). I just don't understand how I can get the base address that comes before 80209B74.